# Delete Query Is not working

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to delete one entry form table by using query my else part is working ... please help me to delete this entry  but i cant so help me in code

enter code here

```
<?php (include 'conn.php');?>

<?php
$del_id=$_GET['del_id'];
//echo "$del_id";
   if(isset($_GET['del_id']))
{
echo "$del_id";

$sel =("DELETE FROM session WHERE sessionid=.'$del_id'");


if(mysql_query($sel))
{
    echo "sucess";
header('location:admin.php');
}
else
{
    echo "not del";
}

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a full-stop after the equals sign, remove it and your code should work fine.

```
$sel = "DELETE FROM session WHERE sessionid=" . $del_id;
```

The full-stop in PHP is used to move from a string to a variable, in this instance you are writing a string of SQL and then you want to move from that string and write a variable, so you use the same quotation that you have used to open the string, then use the full-stop to move from that string to the variable.

Comment: you also don't need surrounding brackets

Answer (score 1):

Just **remove** the **"." (dot)** beside equal sign and use **mysql_query**

`$sel = mysql_query("DELETE FROM session WHERE sessionid = '$del_id'")`;

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error.

```
$sel =("DELETE FROM session WHERE sessionid=$del_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dot AND escape the parameter - especially as you are using the GET value as it is.

```
$sel = "
    DELETE FROM session 
    WHERE sessionid='" . mysql_real_escape_string($del_id) . "'
";
```

This will avoid evil sql injections which could possibly kill all sessions at once.

Just imagine, `$del_id` holds the value `"0' OR '1' = '1"`...

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$sel =mysql_query("DELETE * FROM session WHERE sessionid=$del_id");
```